# Low-pass Filter

Tags: time-series

I collected some data with an instruments with 1Hz sampling clock, now I want to low-pass filter the data to separate the mean and fluctuation part (Reynolds decomposition).
How can I design a low-pass filter with a cutoff period of 20 minutes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you have to use Fourier transform, either in a dirty way by zeroing elements with frequencies you want to filter out or (in a more accurate way, with moving window) by convolution with filter, like in [this MATLAB code example](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/sasp/Example_1_Low_Pass_Filtering.html).

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will try to implement the code in Mathematica Environment.

Comment: I could run the code in Mathematica Environment, but since I'm not familiar with this topic, can you tell me how can I plot the impulse response of this filter? I just could plot the amplitude response.